# Geolocation with Magnetic North

Tags: javascript, math, geolocation, coordinates, compass-geolocation

I'm making an interactive compass which pointing to a static coordinate position (Latitude, Longitude). I read the position of the user with:

```js
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition( positionFound , error );
```

And I rotate the compass with:

```js
heading = Math.atan2( Math.sin(locationLon-userLon) * Math.cos(locationLat), Math.cos(userLat) * Math.sin(locationLat) - Math.sin(userLat) * Math.cos(locationLat) * Math.cos(locationLon-userLon));
heading = heading * 180/Math.PI + 180;
```

Now the problem is that every user gets another pointing position but it must pointing to the same position because they use the same coordinates.

[image: Click to get a picture of the compass page]

Now I found out that when the page has been loaded or refreshed that the North always stay at the first front (North) position of the mobile. And not the real North.
So is there a way to get always the real North position (Magnetic North)?

This is a short demo of it: https://mister-e.nl/compass
(Test it on your mobile and turn your mobile and refresh it sometimes)

This was my first topic (beginner). I hope that I had explained it clear for you guys. And that you maybe can help me with this problem. Tell me if you need to see more code of it.

Answer (score 0):

I leave this here because I wasted a full day with the same problem.
You are looking into the wrong API for getting the Orientation of the phone. The heading attribute in the geolocation is not the compas orientation but a direction calculated based on the movement of the phone. So if you are standing still heading is null. As soon you as you are moving the heading points into the direction of your movement. See this docu: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GeolocationCoordinates/heading

What you are looking for is the "deviceorientation" event. For iOS/Safari you have to manually request the feature first.
(This is Typescript code)

```html
const isIOS = !(
    navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad)/) &&
    navigator.userAgent.match(/AppleWebKit/)
);
if (isIOS) {
    (DeviceOrientationEvent as any).requestPermission()
        .then((response: any) => {
            if (response === "granted") {
                window.addEventListener("deviceorientation", this.receivedNewHeading, true);
            } else {
                alert("has to be allowed!");
            }
        })
        .catch(() => alert("not supported"));
} else {
    window.addEventListener("deviceorientationabsolute", this.receivedNewHeading, true);
}
```